# Why do I need to set ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE in ServletContext?

Tags: spring, servlets, cxf

I running an Apache Tomcat server and deploy my application as a WAR file onto it. Inside the application I created a simple REST resource using Apache CXF.

The `web.xml` only references my listener (`ContextListener`) class.
In this class I create my application context, and add the CXF servlet.

If I leave out the following line, CXF does not work as expected, although the resource bean is registered ("No service was found.").

Could you please explain what this line does, why it is necessary, and which alternatives exist?

`servletContext.setAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, applicationContext);`

Complete file:

```
import xxx.resources.DefaultResource;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.spring.SpringComponentScanServer;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        ServletContext servletContext = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.setServletContext(servletContext);
        applicationContext.register(SpringComponentScanServer.class);
        applicationContext.register(DefaultResource.class);
        applicationContext.refresh();

        Class<CXFServlet> cxfServletClass = CXFServlet.class;
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servletRegistration = servletContext.addServlet(cxfServletClass.getSimpleName(), cxfServletClass);
        servletRegistration.addMapping("/*");

        servletContext.setAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, applicationContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`CXFServlet` (which uses Spring) makes use of Spring's `WebApplicationContextUtils`. This class in turn uses the very same key to retrieve the application context out of the servlet context. In other words, as I am using `CXFServlet`, I need to use this key to store the context.